# login activity unreachable code android

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
  public static final String PREFS_NAME = "IS2013";
  Button btnlogin;
  ImageView btnrate;
  int total = 0;
  TextView txtmsg;
  EditText txtpswd;

  public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    requestWindowFeature(1);
    getWindow().setFlags(1024, 1024);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.txtmsg = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1));
    this.txtpswd = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtpswd));
    this.btnlogin = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogin));
    if (getSharedPreferences("IS2013", 0).getString("pswd", "") != "")
      this.btnlogin.setText("Login");
    while (true)
    {
      this.btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
        {
          String str = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("IS2013", 0).getString("pswd", "");
          if (str == "")
          {
            SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("IS2013", 0).edit();
            localEditor.putString("pswd", MainActivity.this.txtpswd.getText().toString());
            localEditor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password Set", 1000).show();
            Intent localIntent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sms.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent2);
          }
          while (true)
          {

            return;

            // UNREACHABLE CODE---
            if (str.equals(MainActivity.this.txtpswd.getText().toString()))
            {
              Intent localIntent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sms.class);
              MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent1);
            }
            else
            {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Password", 1000).show();
            }
          }
        }
      });

      return;

      // UNREACHABLE CODE---
      this.btnlogin.setText("Create Password");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: well, you always `return;` so the rest is unreachable

Comment: after "return" statement code is not executed.

Comment: Note that this question is not a good question. The OP simply paste the code and did not explain nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Any code after a `return` statement is unreachable.

As soon as execution hits the `return`, method execution stops and control returns to whatever called that method.

I'm not entirely sure what you expect return to do, but it certainly isn't what you are expecting. Why do you return in every iteration of your while loop before you do anything else? A `break` wouldn't make much sense here either, as the code after a break would be just as unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

`return` takes you out of the function and returns some value to whatever called it on the function stack. Try `break`.